# Java video streaming project

Tags: java, video, server, video-streaming, media

I must make a video streaming java program as a project in the university, however I don't know how to start!

I must do both, main-server side and subserver side, the client side is going to be VLC.

So I need help to this points:

- In the main server I must split the videos to say 10KB parts how to
  do that correctly?
- How to stream a video from a sub-server to the    client properly?

**Note:** I prefer to use mp4 videos, but I'm allowd to use whatever I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to decide whether you're building a true live stream (typically Apple HLS or MPEG DASH), or just a pseudo-live stream. Some formats, such as MP4, can be streamed when formatted correctly (see how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615091/java-multimedia-streaming-via-html5-video-element)).

> In the main server I must split the videos to say 10KB parts how to do that correctly?

Sounds like you want to convert a mp4 into a mpeg-ts. Have a look at https://github.com/taktik/mpegts-streamer. Other option is to run [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

> How to stream a video from a sub-server to the client properly?

Multi-source synchronization is a non-trivial matter when it comes to live streams. Depending on your implementation:

1. Pseudo-live stream with MP4: make sure your streaming API supports seeking and restarting. When a client reconnects to another endpoint, it may send HTTP headers to indicate where to continue (not sure if VLC supports this)
2. True live stream: keep track of chunks that were served to the client. Topic or elasticache sound reasonable for that. When a client connects to sub-server for the first time, analyze subscription or query elasticache to determine the best chunk.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at [Ant Media Server](https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server) project which is open source.

Answer (score 1):

Complete example witch stream-m

https://github.com/vbence/stream-m/blob/master/README.md

contains examples of capture and transmission